# Word for someone who steals memories?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English for someone who steals memories?
The idea originated from Harry Potter books. This entity would store memories and later view them in [pensieve](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Pensieve).

Comment: How does that work - the stealing of memories?

Comment: No, not yet.  "Mnemo-rustler"

Comment: Greg, don't you mean mnemoklept?

Comment: Some people go looking for memories. They made a movie: Finding Mnemo.

Comment: Could you give some more context? It sounds interesting. I wouldn't be surprised if it crops up somewhere in literature.

Comment: Exactly, i am asking on behalf of a friend who is writing a novel

Answer (score 4):

There is *kleptomnesiac*.
Actually you can find this using Google, but the meaning is often given as one who steals ideas (usually IP). However klepto- means stealing and -mnesia comes from memory, as in *amnesia* the loss of memory. The -iac suffix translate approximately as *one who*